# How to use preg_replace instead of eregi php function

Tags: preg-replace

When I moved to a new server, eregi function generates too many errors. I like to use preg_replace instead of eregi function.

Here is my block of code:

```
if($rstate && !$rcity && !eregi("outside",$rstate)){
$h1title=str_replace('DDD',$tsstate,str_replace('XXX',$tsstate,$pagetitlet));
echo str_replace('DDD',$tsstate,str_replace('XXX',$tsstate,$pagetitlet));

I changed it to:
if($rstate && !$rcity && !preg_replace("outside",$rstate)){
$h1title=str_replace('DDD',$tsstate,str_replace('XXX',$tsstate,$pagetitlet));
echo str_replace('DDD',$tsstate,str_replace('XXX',$tsstate,$pagetitlet));
```

But it is looking for another value. How do I add the third parameter for preg_replace to get it worked?

Thanks.

Comment: have you looked at the docs? http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a regex for this test, use strpos instead:

```
if ($rstate && !$rcity && strpos($rstate, "outside")===false) {
    $h1title = str_replace('DDD', $tsstate, str_replace('XXX',$tsstate,$pagetitlet));
    echo str_replace('DDD', $tsstate, str_replace('XXX',$tsstate,$pagetitlet));
    ...
}
```

Note that the regex function you are looking for is [preg_match](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)